# Read every character from file

Tags: c

I want to read each element of my text file which includes new lines and also spaces. Here is my code

```
void test3()
{
    char a;
    FILE *csv;
    csv=fopen64("C:\\Users\\Md. Akash\\Desktop\\csv\\Book1.csv","r");
    int i;
    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
        if(fgetc(csv)==EOF)
            break;
        a=fgetc(csv);
        printf("%c",a);
    }
}
```

[image]

This code skips one character.

Comment: That code cannot work with an image. (Although to be fair, you do not tell us what the problem is. It may be that you have an image of text instead of text.)

Comment: i'm using this code for reading csv file not image.

Comment: You aren't saving the value from fgetc so you lose it.

Comment: You're calling `fgetc` twice per loop....

Comment: The source that you show here is an image, not a CSV file. Do not provide an image of text; we cannot test your code with it. Also, still no mention of what the problem is.

Comment: by the time you call `a = fgetc(csv)` you already read one character that you dont store anywhere

Comment: thanks I got it. can you tell me how to check then eof to exit the loop.@lan

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing **for loop** by the following:

```
/*
 Note:
 a = fgetc(csv) returns a character from the file pointed to by **csv** o returns **EOF** if the End Of File is reached.

 Therefore, it is probably a good idea to read every character from the file until the EOF is reached.

 The following **while** loop demonstrate just that.
*/
while((a =fgetc(csv)) != EOF){
     printf("%c", a)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `fgetc` twice in every iteration of the `for` loop. And you are not printing what you get the first time.

**Change:**

```
if(fgetc(csv)==EOF)
    break;
a=fgetc(csv);
printf("%c",a);
```

**to:**

```
if((a = fgetc(csv))==EOF)
    break;        
printf("%c",a);
```

**Note:** [`fgetc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/) returns an `int`. So `a` should be defined as an `int`.